# Using SwiftyJSON wrong?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I am trying to use swiftyJSON for JSON that is stored in a parse column...

I can print out the JSON I'm trying to access..but none of my "if let" statements are printing anything to the logs...hopefully you can help thanks!

[image]

[image]  <----This is the JSON...

this is what I've tried so far..[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your model, you have an array of such entries. You need to enumerate this array before getting string values from there. This code works:

```
    for (_, entry) in thisJSON {
        if let success = entry["freeChlorine"].string {
            println(success)
        }
    }
```